# Как решить проблему с цветом бордера UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть KeyboardView - клавиатура с кнопкапки KeboardButton.
У каждой KeboardButton задан border размером 0.5 пикселей. 
Клавиши соприкасаются друг с другом вплотную, соотвественно получается "общий" border шириной 1px.

```
class KeyboardButton: UIControl {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       layer.borderWidth = 0.5
       layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Проблема в том что вертикальные и горизонтальные линии получаеются разного цвета. Сначала я подумал что это оптимичейский обман.
Потом я сделал скриншот, открыл его в фотошопе и проверил цвета пипеткой, оказалось что они действительно разные.

Почему таки происходит и как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное что-то связанное со сглаживанием. Тень с определенным радиусом тоже не точна по пикселям.

Сделайте не бордер, а отступы на нужное расстояние между кнопками, а вьюшку под кнопками покрасьте в нужный цвет.